# Does python twisted framework HttpClient access proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, networking, twisted

I need to access a webpage using

```
twisted.web.client.getPage()
```

or a similar method to download a webpage from a known address (ie:www.google.com), the problem is: I am behind a proxy server and I couldn't find anywhere explanations on how to configure twisted or factories to use my proxy, any ideas?

Bear in mind I have to specify user, password, host and port.
On my linux machine I setup `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` to `http://user:pwd@ip:port`

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import client

def processResult(page):
    print "I got some data", repr(page)
    reactor.callLater(0.1, reactor.stop)
def dealWithError(err):
    print err.getErrorMessage()
    reactor.callLater(0.1, reactor.stop)

class ProxyClientFactory(client.HTTPClientFactory):
    def setURL(self, url):
        client.HTTPClientFactory.setURL(self, url)
        self.path = url

factory = ProxyClientFactory('http://url_you_want')
factory.deferred.addCallbacks(processResult, dealWithError)

reactor.connectTCP('proxy_address', 3142, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work, although I understand the code is correct, my DNS doesn't recognize the hostname with proxy_address = `http://user:pwd@host:port`

Comment: Yeah, well, authentication is a different beast

Comment: Accepted answer, this one answers my question, I just needed to do a different question :D

Answer (score 1):

To get nosklo's solution to work you will need to create another handler for the '401' that indicates that authentication is required. Try something like this

```
def checkAuthError(self,failure,url):
    failure.trap(error.Error)
    if failure.value.status == '401':
        username = raw_input("User name: ")
        password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
        auth = base64.encodestring("%s:%s" %(username, password))
        header = "Basic " + auth.strip()
        return client.getPage(
            url, headers={"Authorization": header})
    else:
        return failure
```

This will prompt the operator to supply the information at the command line, or you couple could supply the username and password in another way of your choosing. Make sure this is the first handler added as an Errback, before any other handlers are added even the Callback. This also requires a few more imports; 'base64', 'getpass', and 'error' to work with the command line prompts.

Comment: Except, don't use `base64.encodestring()` because it may insert newlines which is Bad. Instead, use `base64.b64encode()`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar using base auth, since the example code for the auth request did not work here is a version that works:

```
import base64

from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from twisted.web import client, error, http

from ubuntuone.devtools.testcases.squid import SquidTestCase

# ignore common twisted lint errors
# pylint: disable=C0103, W0212


class ProxyClientFactory(client.HTTPClientFactory):
    """Factory that supports proxy."""

    def __init__(self, proxy_url, proxy_port, url, headers=None):
        self.proxy_url = proxy_url
        self.proxy_port = proxy_port
        client.HTTPClientFactory.__init__(self, url, headers=headers)

    def setURL(self, url):
        self.host = self.proxy_url
        self.port = self.proxy_port
        self.url = url
        self.path = url


class ProxyWebClient(object):
    """Provide useful web methods with proxy."""

    def __init__(self, proxy_url=None, proxy_port=None, username=None,
            password=None):
        """Create a new instance with the proxy settings."""
        self.proxy_url = proxy_url
        self.proxy_port = proxy_port
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def _process_auth_error(self, failure, url, contextFactory):
        """Process an auth failure."""
        # we try to get the page using the basic auth
        failure.trap(error.Error)
        if failure.value.status == str(http.PROXY_AUTH_REQUIRED):
            auth = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (self.username, self.password))
            auth_header = 'Basic ' + auth.strip()
            factory = ProxyClientFactory(self.proxy_url, self.proxy_port, url,
                    headers={'Proxy-Authorization': auth_header})
            # pylint: disable=E1101
            reactor.connectTCP(self.proxy_url, self.proxy_port, factory)
            # pylint: enable=E1101
            return factory.deferred
        else:
            return failure

    def get_page(self, url, contextFactory=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """Download a webpage as a string.

        This method relies on the twisted.web.client.getPage but adds and extra
        step. If there is an auth error the method will perform a second try
        so that the username and password are used.
        """
        scheme, _, _, _ = client._parse(url)
        factory = ProxyClientFactory(self.proxy_url, self.proxy_port, url)
        if scheme == 'https':
            from twisted.internet import ssl
            if contextFactory is None:
                contextFactory = ssl.ClientContextFactory()
            # pylint: disable=E1101
            reactor.connectSSL(self.proxy_url, self.proxy_port,
                               factory, contextFactory)
            # pylint: enable=E1101
        else:
            # pylint: disable=E1101
            reactor.connectTCP(self.proxy_url, self.proxy_port, factory)
            # pylint: enable=E1101
        factory.deferred.addErrback(self._process_auth_error, url,
                                    contextFactory)
        return factory.deferred
```

Answer (score 0):

We chose to use the `http_proxy` environment variable. We were having trouble with redirections not always getting picked up, or rather getting picked up in the right way. That said, `nosklo`'s response *really* helped!

```
import os
from twisted.web import client

class ProxyClientFactory(client.HTTPClientFactory):
    def setURL(self, url):
        '''More sensitive to redirects that can happen, that
        may or may not be proxied / have different proxy settings.'''
        scheme, host, port, path = client._parse(url)
        proxy = os.environ.get('%s_proxy' % scheme)
        if proxy:
            scheme, host, port, path = client._parse(proxy)
            self.scheme = scheme
            self.host = host
            self.port = port
            self.path = url
            self.url = url
        else:
            client.HTTPClientFactory.setURL(self, url)

factory = ProxyClientFactory(url)
# Callback configuration
# If http_proxy or https_proxy, or whatever appropriate proxy
# is set, then we should try to honor that. We do so simply 
# by overriding the host/port we'll connect to. The client
# factory, BaseRequestServicer takes care of the rest
scheme, host, port, path = client._parse(url)
proxy = os.environ.get('%s_proxy' % scheme)
if proxy:
    scheme, host, port, path = client._parse(proxy)
reactor.connectTCP(host, port, factory)
```